# Why @ContributesAndroidInjector cant be found by DaggerAndroidProcessor library on the processor path?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am implementing Dagger2 and when I am using @ContributesAndroidInjector, I get compile time
error:`@dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector was used,but dagger.android.processor.AndroidProcessor was not found on the processor path`

I tried multiple solutions but this error never goes away. I tried using old library
version of dagger2 dependencies. I tried creating a java abstract @Module class. I
tried using Kotlin android processor declaring kapt dependency, But Nothing really Helped. Can somebody please help me to rid of this error. Following are the dependencies of Dagger2 that I am using in my project for reference:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.35.1"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1"
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.3.0"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.2.1"
```

Comment: Why are you using `kapt` for one but `annotationProcessor` for the other? The [docs](https://github.com/google/dagger#gradle) say to use `kapt` all over, not just for one, assuming you're using Kotlin. I haven't seen your specific error but if those two annotation processors don't match I could imagine the Kotlin annotation phase giving that error if it encounters `@ContributesAndroidInjector` before the Android processor comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! You were not using the same Dagger compiler as your implementations. Your compiler was 2.28.3 and your implementations were 2.35.1. If the Dagger compiler has a different version than its implementation, it may generate non-working code that refers to missing implementations, or (as here) it may not generate code at all.

Make them match:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.35.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35.1"

implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.3.0"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.2.1"
```

I also switched your Android compiler to `kapt` per [the Dagger README section on Gradle](https://github.com/google/dagger#gradle).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by changing my dependencies to the following-

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"
```

This seems to be more like a a hack than a proper solution as when I update my libraries it starts giving me compile time error